# Does System.Threading.Timer have to be disposed programmatically after using it?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using System.Threading.Timer in a windows form. It is declared as private on the form but the timer is initialized from 2 places which are FrmMain_Load() and ToolClick().

FrmMain_Load runs when the application launches for the first time but I need to reset the timer upon ToolClick() and start the timer again.
    So I am trying to call InitializeTimer() from ToolClick(). Is this the right way of stopping and resetting the timer? Also, does it have to be disposed
    explicitly upon closing the form? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
Private timer As System.Threading.Timer

Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    //Other code

    InitializeTimer()
End Sub

Private Sub ToolClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolClickEventArgs) Handles u.ToolClick
    //Other code

    InitializeTimer()
End Sub

 Private Sub InitializeTimer()
    If Items.Visible Then
        Dim refreshCallBack As New System.Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf timer_Tick)
        timer = New System.Threading.Timer(refreshCallBack, Nothing, 0, 60000)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal state As Object)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                        Refresh()
                                    End Sub))
    Else
        Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use that `Timer` in the first place? All you're doing is invoking a method on the UI thread anyway so why not simply use a WinForms `Timer` that raises its `Tick` event on the UI thread in the first place? If you do want to do work on a secondary thread based on the `Timer` then you should still be using a `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: And that line can be `Me.Invoke(Sub() Refresh())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, anything which implements the IDisposable interface must be disposed when it is no longer necessary, even if the form is about to close.

Consider that the closing of the form currently means that the application is terminating, but this fact can quickly change.

Note that an IDisposable implementation could wrap an unmanaged resource and not disposing it could cause various issues if the wrapper type is poorly implemented.

In your case, not disposing of the timer when the form closes will have no effect, but do consider:

What happens if you do not dispose of anything IDisposable? That depends on the type, and on who implemented it.

Best case scenario - you leak a resource until it is somehow garbage collected. Note that this is true only in the case of managed resources.

Worst case scenario, and this is usually the case for unmanaged resource wrappers- resource leaks, OutOfMemoryException and even unmanaged exceptions which crash your application.

So, to stress the short answer- make it a habit to "follow protocol" as far as IDisposable goes.

Feel free to ask further questions in the comments.

Comment: I'd say it strong: i'd say if it implements IDisposable you *must* call .DIspose (or use a using block, if available)

Comment: Also as a side if you don't know if something implements `IDisposable` you can attempt to implement a `Using` block for it and if it doesn't the compiler will tell you.